# Did cold weather cause my Jeep's heater fan to stop blowing and then start again later?

Tags: jeep, grand-cherokee, heater-blower

I just bought a used 2014 Jeep Grand Cherokee Laredo, I've had it for a week.

I brought it in to get the windshield washer nozzles replaced (they were spraying weird).

When I got the car back I drove away and put the heat on "hi" and climate on "auto" (it's *crazy* cold here: -12C/11F).  After a few minutes, I noticed the heater fan wasn't blowing.

It has a UConnect 5 integrated climate control system, the fan speed was turned to max and the heat was set max, but there was no fan noise and no air blowing at all.  And no heat.

I tried a variety of settings -- also shut the car off, opened/closed doors, and restarted it -- but could not get it working.  No blower, no heat, no front defrost, nothing.  I drove it for almost an hour like this before I could bring it back.

The heater/fan had been working every day since I bought the car last week, it seemed too coincidental that the heater would just stop working like that after getting the washer nozzles replaced -- I just assumed they accidentally disconnected something during the nozzle repair.

I brought it back to the service place and showed them the problem and left the car with them.  A couple hours later, when the mechanic took it in to look at the problem, and the fan was now just working fine.  He says there's no problem.  It appears to have fixed itself.

What would cause the fan to just stop working, and then start working again?  I would think if there was a fuse blown, or something got accidentally unplugged, they would just tell me.

One detail that may or may not be important -- They were nice enough to wash the car after replacing the nozzles, and because of the wicked cold, some stuff was noticeably frozen, like the power windows wouldn't go up and down because they were frozen.

Is it possible the cold and the car wash froze something related to the heater/fan and it later just warmed up / thawed out when the mechanic brought it into the garage?

Any ideas what happened to my heater-blower?

Comment: Does there seem to be any correlation between engine temp and the heater fan working? With the fan set on heat will it only blow when the engine is hot? So as not to blow cold air.

Comment: @mikes I'm pretty sure the fan used to blow cold air even when the engine was cold, but I'll try again tomorrow morning when the car is dead cold. Are you suggesting it might be normal for the car to now blow air until it's temperature is high enough?  Because I drove the car for almost an hour before returning to the dealer and the fan wouldn't kick in -- even on the coldest days, a normal car will produce heat after 10 or 15 minutes. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Some climate control systems are pretty smart that's why I suggested the possible connection. I agree it should have been warm enough after an hour. Just check the engine temp gauge and let us know. Also try to wiggle the ignition switch and see if it helps.

Comment: @mikes thanks -- i'll observe it tomorrow morning (-15C!!) and report back; just fyi, the ignition is a "start" button, not as manly as keys unfortunately ;-)

Comment: Are you still having this issue?  Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: @DucatiKiller Never had the problem again. I've had the Jeep for a full year in plenty of crazy hot and crazy cold weather.  I'm going to assume that when they replaced the windshield washer nozels, they accidentally unplugged the power to the fan.  Then they fixed it and were embarrassed to say they made a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a year later.

I never had the problem again. I've had the Jeep for a full year in plenty of crazy hot and crazy cold weather. I'm going to assume that when they replaced the windshield washer nozels, they accidentally unplugged the power to the fan. Then they fixed it and were embarrassed to say they made a mistake.

If anyone else experiences the same weird problem, please post a comment, I'm still curious to know if there was really a mechanical or electrical problem.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to put the solution in and getting this marked as answered.  Appreciated.  Happy New Year!